# -ms-scroll not work in ie10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am trying to crate custom scrollbar using `CSS` and it's respectively working in chrome but in Internet Explorer, It fails.Here is my `CSS` for Chrome and IE

**CHROME**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment  {
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

**IE**

```
::-ms-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
}

::-ms-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-ms-scrollbar-button:end:increment  {
    display: none;
}

::-ms-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: white;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
}

::-ms-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}

::-ms-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}

::-ms-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) url(scrollbar_thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

I am using Internet Explorer 10. 
Above code can't work in IE.have anyone any idea?

Comment: Have you tried it without the `-ms-` and `-webkit-` prefixes?

Comment: yaa but it's not working..

Comment: As a rudimentary workaround, you can still use the `scrollbar-xxx-color` properties in IE10. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx As far as I can tell, no RGBA colors though.